# Split Sentence if it ends with period but not number containing decimal

Tags: c#, split

I want to split my text into sentences, each sentence end with `.`, but exclude number with decimal point.

I used split function. but it splits the number into two parts, I don't want to split the number.

example :

> My package a mount is 85.5 daily, how can I make use of it. any body
>   has an idea for that. please let me know.

should be splited to:

> My package a mount is 85.5 daily, how can I make use of it
>
> any body has an idea for that
>
> please let me know

Comment: Have you tried anything? Start with simple rules and build up... I.e. if it is a `.` and nothing afterwards, done. If it is a `.` with a space afterwards you can split. If it is a `.` and a `CR+LF` you can split etc...

Comment: Is the rule this? Split on `.` except if the `.` contains a digit on both sides?

Comment: I can Iterate on my text character by character, but I want to use more efficient function like split , regex .... etc , thanks

Comment: Maybe split on "period space", instead of a plain "period"?

Comment: what about `"This is an interesting idea... Because is this a break or continuation"` ?

Comment: @Belogix , it is not important, I can ignore results with length of 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dmitry Bychenko's answer is simple and nice, however it'll lose a character right after .(dot)

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)");
var myText = @"My package a mount is 85.5 daily, how can I make use of it. any body has an idea for that. please let me know.";

Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(myText, Environment.NewLine));
```

It will consume only .(dot) character that is not followed nor preceded by digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "period space" as a delimiter:

```
string source = "My package amount is 85.5 daily, how can I make use of it. Anybody has an idea for that? Please let me know.";

string[] splits = Regex.Split(source, @"[\.?!]\s+");
```

This also sentences ending in `!` or `?` and takes any number of spaces (and other whitespace chars) with a minimum of one.

And if you want to keep the period, search for a space preceded by that line-end symbol:

```
string[] splits2 = Regex.Split(source, @"(?<=[\.?!])\s+");
```